# sort a python dictionary using specail characer

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, hash

I want to sort a python dictionay based on special characters.

```
s = {"a":"hi@gmail.com","b":"s.s@gmail.com","c":"d.d@gmail.com","a":"s@gmail.com"}
sorted(s,".")
print s
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_re.py", line 2, in <module>
    sorted(s,".")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Expected output if it has special character

```
{"b":"s.s@gmail.com","c":"d.d@gmail.com","a":"hi@gmail.com","a":"s@gmail.com"}
```

Expected output if it dont have special character

```
{"a":"hi@gmail.com","a":"s@gmail.com","b":"s.s@gmail.com","c":"d.d@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: What you mean by "sorted using special characters?"

Comment: sorted by . incase is key has s.s then it shud displayed first

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort a dictionary, but you can sort it's keys. Try this:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(s, key=lambda key: '.' in s[key])
```

Then you can access your items in the order you want to.

---

You could also use `OrderedDict` from `collections` module

```
from collections import OrderedDict    

sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(s.items(), key=lambda item: '.' in item[1]))
```

It acts as a usual `dict` in almost any way, except for printing it. If you want to print it like if it was a usual `dict`, you can use `json` module

```
import json

print(json.dumps(sorted_dict))
```

It may cause you trouble if there are any non JSON-compatible things in the dictionary, but if it's like in your example, you're good.

Comment: yeah but still this is the output OrderedDict([('a', 'hi@gmail.com'), ('c', 'd.d@gmail.com'), ('b', 's.s@gmail.com'), ('v', 's@gmail.com')])